# Is there a way of extracting xpath and text from webpage and save to file?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, dictionary, xpath

I am looking for handy tool to extract UIElement's Object Type and Xpath/ID/Name from webpage or any alternative instead of Inspecting the element from Browser? Also any alternative to extract text from Webpage.
I want to save this in a separate Excel or Text file. Any suggestion how to go about it?

I am saving it manually by inspecting the UIElement object on the webpage and saving it (space separated) on to file. Then reading it using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an XPath, you can use the following process in the Firefox browser:

- Select the element and then <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> it.
- Select "Inspect Element" to enter the *Developer Tools*
- <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the highlighted element and select

  > Copy -> XPath

Now you have (a very basic version of) the XPath-1.0 expression of the selected element in the ClipBoard.

Of course, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to get it from there.

This does work for one element.
For several elements you have to repeat the process;
I don't know of a way to select several node items at once.
In other browsers the process is probably similar.

---

Second step:
To extract the values/partial HTML selected by the XPath, use a program like `xmlstarlet` or similar and redirect its output to a file.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually..so looking for a way that atleast selects all elements and i can paste into a file. Or any tool /plugin like that. I heard excel has a plugin but not sure how to install that.